# How to connect neo4j with bolt protocol in gremlin-server?

Tags: neo4j, gremlin-server

I want to run gremlin-server and neo4j together.

So I make to run neo4j docker image in my machine, and try to connect it with BOLT protocol.

Could anyone help to configure .yaml/.property file in gremlin-server for this?

Used version | gremlin-server 3.4.0 & neo4j 3.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration options for the `Graph` instance property file can be found [here](https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt/blob/df3ab429e0c83affae6cd43d41edd90de80c032e/src/main/java/com/steelbridgelabs/oss/neo4j/structure/Neo4JGraphConfigurationBuilder.java#L32-L42). I'm not sure what the minimum requirements are for this provider, but from a TinkerPop perspective you need to at least specify the `Graph` instance with `gremlin.graph` and then include whatever other configurations you need to connect:

```
gremlin.graph=com.steelbridgelabs.oss.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraphFactory
neo4j.hostname=...
neo4j.port=...
```

Then in the Gremlin Server [yaml file](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/34136537738405b1703804565faba6866fb3e3b1/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server.yaml#L22-L23) you just reference the path to the above property file.

```
graphs: {
  graph: conf/bolt.properties}
```